# C# WMI Process Differentiation?

Tags: c#, wmi

#### Scenario

I have a method that returns a list of processes using WMI.
If I have 3 processes running (all of which are C# applications) - and they all have THE SAME PROCESS NAME but different command line arguments, how can I differentiate between them If I want to start them or terminate them!?

#### Thoughts

As far as I can see, I physically cannot differentiate between them, at least not without having to use the Handle, but that doesn't tell me which one of them got terminated because the others will still sit there with the same name........

....really stumped, help greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there any way u can get the process ID when you're first starting these processes?

Comment: Why not use `Handle`? it's the key property anyway.

Comment: Combine those two comments: the `Handle` property *is* the process ID

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "if I want to start them"? Do you mean something like "I want to start a fourth process with the same name, how can I later identify that particular instance to terminate it?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMI **[Win32_ProcessObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx)** has a **CommandLine** property you could use if that is what you know differentiates the instances.

```
string query = “Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = “ + processName;
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
{
     string cmdLine = obj.GetPropertyValue("CommandLine").ToString();

     if (cmdLine == "target command line options")
     {
          // do work
     }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that you need `SeDebugPrivilege` to read `Win32_Process.CommandLine`, so it is usually not possible to read this property remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Create the process using a technique that gives you the process ID as an out parameter. E.g.

- WMI: [Win32_Process.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388.aspx) method returns `[out]  uint32 ProcessId`
- .NET: [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method returns a Process object with a [Process.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx) property

Then you can use that value to truly know which version of the process you want to kill later. E.g.

- WMI: Get Win32_Process instance matching ProcessId, call [Terminate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393907.aspx)
- .NET: Get Process instance using GetProcessById, call [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) and then [WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx)

(Note that if the process stops before you kill it, the OS can assign that same process ID to a new process, so of course you'll want to double check that you're killing the right one, e.g. check the process name too)